# Kendo Grid enter key press event handling

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

In a Kendo-grid I have to Manage enter key event.If a user press Enter Key inside a cell ,The cell focus must be move to a given cell index and put it to editabale mode.For textbox i Have done that part but for Kendo Dropdown it only focus but not change to edit mode.
My code is

```
   edit: function (e) {

            var sender = e.sender;
            var cellToEdit = sender.content.find("td:eq(0)");


            var input = e.container.find(".k-input");
            var td = input.closest("td");
            var rowIndex = td.parent().index();
            var cellIndex = td.index();

            input.on("keydown", function (event) {

                if (event.keyCode == 13) {

                    debugger;//Check the current cell index
                    if (cellIndex == 2) {
                        debugger;
                        cellIndex = 3;//wanted to focus cell index next

                        var cellCloseT = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").closeCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").parent());
                        $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").editCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").next().focusin(cellCloseT));
                        return false;

                    }
                    else if (cellIndex == 4) {
                        debugger;
                        cellIndex = 5;

                        var cellCloseT = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").closeCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").parent());
                        $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").editCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").next().focusin(cellCloseT).editCell($(".k-grid-content")));
                        sender.editCell(cellToEdit);
                        return false;

                    }
                    else if (cellIndex == 6) {
                        debugger;
                        cellIndex = 7;

                        var cellCloseT = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").closeCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").parent());
                        $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").editCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").next().focusin(cellCloseT));
                        return false;

                    }

                    else if (cellIndex == 8) {
                        debugger;
                        cellIndex = 8;

                        var cellCloseT = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").closeCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").parent());
                        $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").editCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").next().focusin(cellCloseT));
                        return false;

                    } else if (cellIndex == 9) {
                        debugger;
                        cellIndex = 9;

                        var cellCloseT = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").closeCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").parent());
                        $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").editCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").next().focusin(cellCloseT));
                        return false;

                    }



                   //else if (cellIndex == 11 || cellIndex == 12) {



                   //     CreateNewGridRow();


                   //     var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                   //     //grid.dataSource.read();
                   //     var count = grid.dataSource.total();
                   //     setRow(count, e.model);
                   //     balance();

                   // }

                }
                //else if (event.keyCode == 13) {

                //     if (cellIndex == 11 || cellIndex == 12) {



                //         CreateNewGridRow();


                //         var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                //         //grid.dataSource.read();
                //         var count = grid.dataSource.total();
                //         setRow(count, e.model);
                //         balance();

                //     }

                //}
            })


            }
```

Comment: Can you give us a minimal working example via js fiddle?

Comment: My Updated Code Please try this
[DemoCode](http://jsfiddle.net/Suranga286/2NrLR/78/)

Comment: In your demo, when you press enter in the first column field, it goes to the second column field of the same row, then when press enter again, it returns to the previous field. Is that ok ? The third column doens't change focus at all. If I got you right, it should change to the forth column in edit mode of the drodpdown ?

Comment: Actually i need like this if user press enter key in the first column it should go to the second column of the same row.then when press the enter it should go to the forth column Dropdownlist  and it should me editable.it must be editable not only focus.
Can you give me a sample code